# Loop Through A PivotField

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

This could be quite a simple question, but I am trying to loop through the items on a `PivotField` using VBA. I have written:

```
Dim PT As PivotTable
Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
Dim Country As Variant

For Each Country In PT.PivotFields("Country")

'Code inserted here

Next Country
```

However I am met with a Run-Time error 438. I would like to cycle through each country (Albania, Belgium, Canada etc) in the `PivotField` and run a macro for the data associated with that country. How can I do so?